# How can I scale a unity sprite programmatically to a fractional number of units?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've spawned a tile as follows:

```
private GameObject SpawnTile(int col, int row, Color color, GameObject parent, string label)
    {
        GameObject g = new GameObject("C: " + col + " R: " + row);
        g.transform.position = world_grid.GetWorldPosition(col, row);
        g.transform.localScale = new Vector3(world_grid.cell_size, world_grid.cell_size);

        g.transform.parent = parent.transform;
        return g;
    }
```

I then add a spriterenderer, and display a sprite of a given color.

```
tile.game_object = SpawnTile(col, row, color, parent, label);

tile.sprite_renderer = tile.game_object.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
tile.sprite_renderer.sprite = tile_sprite;
//Bounds bounds = tile.sprite_renderer.bounds;
tile.sprite_renderer.color = color;
```

I have the ability to display grids using this mechanism. I can scale the size of a tile up by an integer amount. However when I try to scale the object down, the sprite does not scale down with it.

In the following, I have 3 1x1 grids. The grid on the right has a cell_size of 2. The grid in the middle has a cell_size of 1. The grid on the left has a cell_size of 0.5.

The "tile" object is of an appropriate size. As we see this object is shown as half size in Unity's Scene View. However in the game view on the right, it shows as the same size as the pink grid in the middle.

[image]

Further details, I have spent quite a bit of time trying to figure this out, and though I see a variety of posts that seem to relate to sprite sizing, none of them are clear for a relative unity beginner.

Some of the posts I've found seem to suggest that I need to use the sprite renderer bounds to ensure that the sprite is proeprly sized. But its not clear to me how.

This is my grid class. Notice that it is constructed with a cell_size (in units). Notice that when I create the object of a given size, I size the object, but not the sprite.

```
public class WorldGrid<TGridObject> : Grid<TGridObject>
{

    public float cell_size { get; private set; }
    // Defines the center point in world coordinates
    public Vector3 center_point { get; private set; }

    public WorldGrid(Vector3 _center_point,  int _columns, int _rows, float _cell_size) : base(_columns, _rows)
    {
        cell_size = _cell_size;
        center_point = _center_point;
    }

    public Vector3 GetWorldPosition(int col, int row)
    {
        float x_pos = col * cell_size + cell_size / 2f;
        float y_pos = row * cell_size + cell_size / 2f; 

        // wp = cp + gp
        return center_point + new Vector3(x_pos, y_pos); 
    }

    public void GetGridPosition(Vector3 world_position, out int col, out int row)
    {
        // gp = wp - cp
        // position in grid-centered reference frame
        Vector3 gp = world_position - center_point;

        row = Mathf.FloorToInt(gp.y / cell_size);
        col = Mathf.FloorToInt(gp.x / cell_size);
    }

    public void SetValue(Vector3 world_position, TGridObject value) 
    {
        int row, col;
        GetGridPosition(world_position, out row, out col);
        SetValue(row, col, value);
    }
}
```

This references a lower level grid class (that is not in world units):

```
public class Grid<TGridObject>
{
    public int columns { get; private set; }
    public int rows { get; private set; }
    public TGridObject[,] grid { get; private set; }

    private int cnt = 0;

    public event EventHandler<OnGridCellValueChangedEventArgs> OnGridCellValueChanged;
    public class OnGridCellValueChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int cnt;
        public int row;
        public int column;
    }

    public Grid(int _columns, int _rows)
    {
        columns = _columns;
        rows = _rows;
        grid = new TGridObject[columns, rows];
    }

    public void SetValue(int col, int row, TGridObject value)
    {
        if((row >= 0 && row < rows) &&
            (col >= 0 && col < columns))
        {
            grid[col, row] = value;
            if(OnGridCellValueChanged != null)
            {
                cnt += 1;
                Debug.LogError("Triggering [" + col + "," + row + "] of [" + columns + "," + rows + "]");
                OnGridCellValueChanged(this, 
                    new OnGridCellValueChangedEventArgs { row = row, column = col, cnt = cnt }
                    ); 
            }
        }
    }

    public TGridObject GetValue(int col, int row)
    {
        if ((row >= 0 && row < rows) &&
            (col >= 0 && col < columns))
        {
            return grid[col, row];
        } else
        {
            return default(TGridObject);
        }
    }
}
```

I instantiate grids using a GridManager class:

```
public class GridManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    private struct WorldGridDescriptor
    {
        public int rows;
        public int columns;
        public float cell_size;
        public Vector3 center_point;
        public bool randomize_start;
    }

    public Sprite tile_sprite;
    public int world_size_factor = 1;
    private int columns, rows;
    private float unit_step_size = 1.0f;
    private List<WorldGrid<float>> world_grids = new List<WorldGrid<float>>();
    private List<GridView> world_grid_views = new List<GridView>();
    [SerializeField] private List<WorldGridDescriptor> world_grid_descriptors;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // The orthographic size specifies the camera units from
        // the horizontal centerline to the top of screen

        // The vertical_units are then the number of tile rows
        // from the centerline to the top of screen

        rows = (int)Camera.main.orthographicSize * world_size_factor * 2;
        float aspect_ratio = ((float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height);
        columns = (int)(rows * aspect_ratio);

        // Will parent the tiles in the empty Grid. 
        // Perhaps this container should be public. 
        // For now it is a hard-coded assumption, that it exists.
        GameObject grid_container = this.gameObject.transform.Find("Grid").gameObject;
        if (world_grid_descriptors != null)
        {
            foreach (WorldGridDescriptor wgd in world_grid_descriptors)
            {
                WorldGrid<float> wg = new WorldGrid<float>(wgd.center_point, wgd.columns, wgd.rows, wgd.cell_size);
                if(wgd.randomize_start)
                {
                    RandomizeState(wg);
                }
                GridView grid_view = new GridView(wg, tile_sprite, grid_container);
                world_grids.Add(wg);
                world_grid_views.Add(grid_view);
            }
        }
    }

    private void RandomizeState(WorldGrid<float> g)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < g.columns; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < g.rows; row++)
            {
                g.SetValue(col, row, Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f));
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Vector3 worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            foreach (WorldGrid<float> wg in world_grids)
            {
                int c, r;
                wg.GetGridPosition(worldPosition, out c, out r);
                wg.SetValue(c, r, Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f));
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Lastly, the view into the grids are created as follows (this shows you exactly how I create the grid representation that uses a sprite renderer component to render sprites for each cell in the grid):

```
public class GridView 
{
    public struct Tile
    {
        public GameObject game_object;
        public SpriteRenderer sprite_renderer;
        public TextMesh text_mesh;
    }

    private Tile[,] tiles;

    private WorldGrid<float> world_grid;
    protected Sprite tile_sprite { get; private set; }
    public GridView(WorldGrid<float> wg, Sprite ts, GameObject parent)
    {
        world_grid = wg;
        tile_sprite = ts;
        tiles = new Tile[wg.columns, wg.rows];
        wg.OnGridCellValueChanged += OnGridCellValueChanged;
        Create(parent);
    }

    private void Create(GameObject parent)
    {

        for (int col = 0; col < world_grid.columns; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < world_grid.rows; row++)
            {
                Tile tile = new Tile();

                float r, g, b;
                r = g = b = world_grid.grid[col, row];
                float a = 1f;
                Color color = new Color(r, g, b, a);
                string label = (string)((int)(255 * world_grid.grid[col, row])).ToString("x");
                tile.game_object = SpawnTile(col, row, color, parent, label);

                tile.sprite_renderer = tile.game_object.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
                tile.sprite_renderer.sprite = tile_sprite;
                //Bounds bounds = tile.sprite_renderer.bounds;
                tile.sprite_renderer.color = color;
                tile.text_mesh = UtilsClass.CreateWorldText(label, parent.transform, 
                    tile.game_object.transform.position, 7, Color.red, TextAnchor.MiddleCenter);
                tiles[col, row] = tile;
            }
        }
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    private GameObject SpawnTile(int col, int row, Color color, GameObject parent, string label)
    {
        GameObject g = new GameObject("C: " + col + " R: " + row);
        g.transform.position = world_grid.GetWorldPosition(col, row);
        g.transform.localScale = new Vector3(world_grid.cell_size, world_grid.cell_size);

        g.transform.parent = parent.transform;
        return g;
    }

    private void OnGridCellValueChanged(object sender, Grid<float>.OnGridCellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.LogError(e.cnt + " - Updating [" + e.column + "," + e.row + "]");
        Update(e.row, e.column);
    }

    private void Update(int row, int col)
    {

        if (row >= 0 && row < world_grid.rows && col >= 0 && col < world_grid.columns)
        {
            Tile tile = tiles[col, row];
            float r, g, b;
            r = g = b = world_grid.grid[col, row];
            float a = 1f;
            Color color = new Color(r, g, b, a);
            string label = (string)((int)(255 * world_grid.grid[col, row])).ToString("x");
            tile.text_mesh.text = label;
            tile.sprite_renderer.color = color;
        }
    }


}
```

My sprites are a simple blank image that is 256 x 256 pixels in size. I then set the pixels per unit (in the unity editor) to 256.

How can I scale the sprite so that it aligns properly with the spawned tile?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my only issue was in the Display setting.

I had been using a 10x10 display.
[image]

When I changed it to something more reasonable, I realized that my gameobjects were being displayed and selected as expected.

[image]